# Dark area in the paraview python screen shot

Tags: python, paraview

I was working on a python script which runs with pvbatch on a server.

It create a slice of a vtm file and store it as a png file.

The screen shot looks fine when I run the script directly on the server. However, when I remotely log on the server via ssh, the screen shot looks dark:
[image: left image: remote, right image: direct]

left image: remote, right image: direct
I tired to change the lighting using:

```
 slice1Display.Specular = 0.0
 slice1Display.Opacity = 1.0
```

But it doesn't work. Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVM guys, just found a helpful link: [enter link description here](http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-paraview/92638-dark-areas-paraview.html)

Looks like this solved my problem:

```
RenderView1 = GetRenderView() 

# Turn off "Head Light" 
RenderView1.LightSwitch = 0 

# Turn off "Light Kit" 
RenderView1.UseLight = 0 

r = GetDisplayProperties(slice,RenderView1) 
r.Ambient = 1.0 
r.Diffuse = 0.0
```