# Paraview visualization too dark

Tags: visualization, paraview

I'm plotting some water column data in Paraview.  I used delauney3D to go from a set of points to a 3D solid.  Everything works fine, but for some reason the color of the resulting solid is very dark.

As you can see in the screen shot, the actual solid is much darker than the scale bar.

[image: paraview_screenshot]

I haven't come up with any answers by googling or by trying different settings for color.  I would really like to figure out a way to lighten the solid, because the current coloration detracts from the visualization.

I'm using Paraview 4.4.0 32-bit with Windows 7.

Comment: This seems to be a problem of light. You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34146882/5142427, it helped me for a similar problem.

Comment: I agree, this looks like a lighting problem. I would not expect the default lighting to look like that. Any chance you have played with the lights editor dialog? Do you get similar lighting with other geometry? With coloring set to "solid color"? It could also be an issue ParaView is having with the video driver for some reason. Any chance you can try this with ParaView 5.0? That is using completely different rendering under the covers.

Comment: Paraview 5.0 crashes on open on this computer.  I haven't changed any of the default lighting options.  Just for whatever reason, shapes are dark in paraview on this computer and it's been bugging me.